# Filtering by Two Columns in a Dataframe

Tags: r

I'm reading a .csv and need to find the top 5 carriers that sent the most total weight of goods to or from AFRICOM. The "to" column is labeled `SPOE_AOR` and the "from" column is `SPOD_AOR`. The 'carrier' column is `CARRIERS` and the weight column is `WEIGHT`.

I can't quite figure out how to filter the dataframe such that it only displays the top 5 weights to/from AFRICOM. I'm using diplyr, as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for top 5 to/from as two separate lists or just the top 5 *either to or from* AFRICOM?

Either way, this should help.  The way I'm doing it below is to use `head(df, n)` to display the top `n` from your dataframe.  A combination of `arrange()` to sort (`desc()` for descending order), and `dplyr::filter()` to select your conditions:

```
head(
    df %>% arrange(desc(WEIGHT)) %>%
    dplyr::filter(SPOE_AOR=='AFRICOM' | SPOD_AOR=='AFRICOM')
, 5)
```

That gives you top 5 *either to or from* AFRICOM.  For individual top 5s:

```
#top 5 to:
head(
    df %>% arrange(desc(WEIGHT)) %>%
    dplyr::filter(SPOE_AOR=='AFRICOM')
, 5)

#top 5 from:
head(
    df %>% arrange(desc(WEIGHT)) %>%
    dplyr::filter(SPOE_AOD=='AFRICOM')
, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with `data.table`:

1. First, make sure you store your data (I assume it's called `dt`) as a data.table.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(dt)
```

2. Select all entries that either come from or go out to AFRICOM (a), sum them up (b) by `CARRIERS` (c), order them by this sum (d), and display the first five (e).

```
dt[SPOE_AOR == "AFRICOM" | SPOD_AOR == "AFRICOM", # (a)
   .(TOTAL = sum(WEIGHT)),  # (b)
   CARRIERS][ # (c)
       order(TOTAL, decreasing = TRUE)][ # (d)
           1:5] # (e)
```

If you have never worked with `data.table`, this might seem awfully complicated at first sight. But it is fairly easy to learn, and it gives you great flexibility and performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a solution with base R (without `dplyr` or `data.table`), you could use the `aggregate` function to sum up the weights by carriers; for this, only use cases that either come from or go out to AFRICOM:

```
total_weights <- aggregate(WEIGHT ~ CARRIERS, 
          data = dt[dt$SPOE_AOR == "AFRICOM" | dt$SPOD_AOR == "AFRICOM", ],
          sum)
```

Then, display the top five:

```
head(total_weights[order(total_weights$WEIGHT, decreasing = TRUE), ], 5)
```